# Get wireless domain name programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send `HttpWebRequest` under the network that behind the proxy authentication.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.Method = "POST";
req.Proxy = new WebProxy("192.168.0.2", 8080);
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
req.Proxy.Credentials =new NetworkCredential("username","password","DOMAINNAME");

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
```

Now i want to get the `DOMAINNAME` of wireless network that i connected to it. So, how can i get the wireless network domain name that specifies with `192.168.0.2` host name ?

Thanks for your advance :)

Comment: DOMAIN NAME, not SSID? Right?

Comment: Yes, Domain name. For example, the network of my university, has `SSID=EEKNTU` but `DomainName=ee_net`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) management class, which exposes the `DNSDomain` property, which is probably what you want. Check out the `System.Management` namespace for the classes that access ManagementClass objects.

For instance, this snippet will give you a collection of objects, one for each network adapter on the current machine, and print its DNS Domain property.

```
var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
foreach (var networkAdapter in mc.GetInstances())
{
    Console.WriteLine(networkAdapter.Properties["DNSDomain"].Value);
}
```

Comment: I can not find the class Win32_NetworkAdaptorConfiguration. Could you please give me an example of using this management class ?

Comment: I have tested your typed example code, but .NET 4.0 could not find the ManagementClass :-/ What do i do ?

Comment: Add a reference to System.Management, then.

Comment: ManagementClass haven't included in my autocomplete list.

Comment: Your autocomplete list isn't your code, it's a tool to help you find things quicker. Learn about the components of the .NET framework (System.Management), how to find information about them ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx](MSDN)) and how to add a reference to them in your project. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not going to work. The domain name you are after is part of the **credential** that will be used to get through the authenticating proxy. As such, you need to get it from the same place that you get the username and password from (i.e. probably typed in by a user). Getting the domain from the wireless network (or even the machine) does not guarantee that it matches the domain that the user being used belongs to.

As an example:

> *Contoso Ltd* has a domain called *contoso.local* (which has the W2k alias *CONTOSO*).
>   Their users log onto the domain as *CONTOSO\bob.smith*.
>   Their SSID of their wireless network is *ContosoLtd*.
>
> The correct domain name to use for the proxy credentials is *CONTOSO*.

When you ask for the username and password to use as credentials, ask for the domain name as well.

Comment: If you use the programs like `Firefox` and `Internet Explorer`, you can see that, Firefox only gives username and password and detects domain name automatically, but Internet Explorer needs to type domain name exactly. So, i think that there is a way to get the domain name programmatically.

Comment: @HosseinMobasher: There is a way to get a domain name programmatically, but like I said in my answer - there is no guarantee that it matches the one needed for the specified user. There might be a mechanism whereby a default domain is picked up from somewhere, but I cannot test it at the moment as I'm not currently on a domain.